# How to get a Sharepoint List elements from datasource

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have got 3 list. I make from them one Data Source. How could I get from them one corelated list. How could I connect Data Source into one list?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to implement a linked data source? Do you think this would be what you are going for?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-linked-data-source-HA010355748.aspx